# Forcing IDictionary key to be within specific class type

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have the following member variable:

```
private IDictionary<Type, int> foo = ...
```

The keys must be of BaseClass, SubClass1, or SubClass2. E.g. of insertion:

```
foo.Add(typeof(BaseClass), ...);
foo.Add(typeof(SubClass1), ...);
foo.Add(typeof(SubClass2), ...);
```

Any classes not from the same hierarchy should not be allowed to be added.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Comment: Why are you using `Type` as the key? Any reason you can't make it a `Dictionary<BaseClass, int>`? you could still add `SubClass1` and `SubClass2`

Comment: @RyanWilson I want the type instead of the reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by using a generic type parameter and specifying a constraint on that type parameter.

```
private IDictionary<Type, int> foo = ...

public void Add<T>(T key, int value) where T : BaseClass
{
    foo.Add(typeof(T), value);
}
```

Any classes which are not derived from `BaseClass` will not be allowed because of the `where T : BaseClass` constraint.

There is another way to do this by checking the type while adding to the dictionary.

```
public void Add(Type key, int value)
{
    if (key.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass)))
    {
        foo.Add(key, value);
    }
```

Comment: IOW, you need to write a wrapper around Dictionary/IDicationary that enforces the constraints. There is no direct way to achieve this using `System.Collections.Generic.Dicationary<>` type. This might be obvious to you, but it might not be for the OP.

Comment: @Christian.K right